# Given the texture in the right way

Tags: ios, uiimage, scenekit

[image]

So as you can see, the texture of the photoFrame is a square image. But when I set it to the diffuse contents, the effect is terrible. So how can I display the square image in the rectangle frame but not stretch the image.

Comment: Have you achieved this? If yes then how you get this contentTransform? I am also looking for the same case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of what you see depends on what geometry the texture is mapped onto. Assuming those picture frames are `SCNPlane` or `SCNBox` geometries, the face of the frame has texture coordinates ranging from `(0,0)` in the upper left to `(1,1)` in the lower right, regardless of the geometry's dimensions or aspect ratio.

SceneKit texture maps images such that the top left of the image is at texture coordinate `(0,0)` and the lower right is at `(1,1)` regardless of the pixel dimensions of the image. So, unless you have a geometry whose aspect ratio matches that of the texture image, you're going to see cases like this where the image gets stretched.

There are a couple of things you can do to "fix" your texture:

1. Know (or calculate) the aspect ratios of your image and the geometry (face) you want to put it on, then use the material's `contentsTransform` to correct the image.

   For example, if you have an `SCNPlane` whose width is 2 and height is 1, and you assign a square image to it, the image will get stretched horizontally. If you set the `contentsTransform` to a matrix created with `SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1,2,1)` it'll double the texture coordinates in the horizontal direction, effectively scaling the image in half in that direction, "fixing" the aspect ratio for your 2:1 plane. Note that you might also need a translation, depending on where you want your half-width image to appear on the face of the geometry.

   If you're doing this in the scene editor in Xcode, `contentsTransform` is the "offset", "scale", and "rotation" controls in the material editor, down below where you assigned an image in your screenshot.
2. Know (or calculate) the aspect ratio of your geometry, and at least some information about the size of your image, and create a modified texture image to fit.

   For example, if you have a 2:1 plane as above, and you want to put 320x480 image on it, create a new texture image with dimensions of 960x480 — that is, matching the aspect ratio of the plane. You can use this image to create whatever style of background you want, with your 320x480 image composited on top of that background at whatever position you want.

Comment: Hey, trying to play with the contentsTransform. I am not understand the Matrix work.

Comment: Please show me one more example. Now I have a Plane with two materials. Its width and height are 935.473 and 1349.419. and I have a 1:1 picture, I want to set it to the diffuse property. This picture should show in the center of the plane. So how can I do by using to SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation and SCNMatrix4MakeScale function. Thanks a lot. sorry about my poor english written skill. Can you understand my question?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I change the scale and offset and WrapT property in the material editor. And the effect is good. But when I run it, I couldn't get the same effect. So I try to program by change the contentsTransform property. But the scale, offset they both affect the contentsTransform. So if the offSet is (0, -4.03) and the Scale is (1, 1,714), what is the contentsTransform?

Comment: This is not an answer, this is more detail for the question, you should edit your OP or add a comment.